# How to configure a route of extracting data from the same table in laravel

Tags: laravel

I have a show method which is showing animals from a specific farm.
I wanted to add another option of the element of the same farm but with a specific condition, for instance age <= 2.

This is what I have tried so far

routes(vaccine1)

```
Route::get('/clinic/{animal}/create', 'ClinicController@create');
Route::post('/clinic/{animal}', 'ClinicController@store');
Route::get('/clinic/{animal}/{clinic}/edit', 'ClinicController@edit');
Route::get('/clinic/{farm}', 'ClinicController@show');
Route::get('/clinic/{farm}', 'ClinicController@vaccine1')->name('vaccine1');
```

Controller

```
public function show($id) {
    $farms = User::with(['animals'])->findOrFail($id);
    return view('clinic.show',compact('farms'));
}

public function vaccine1($id) {
    $farms = User::with(['animals'])->findOrFail($id);
    return view('clinic.show',compact('farms'));
}
```

and the view link from show

```
<li class="nav-item dropdown pr-3">
    <a href="#" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" v-pre>
        Vaccines <span class="caret"></span>
    </a>

    <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="{{ route('vaccine1') }}">
            0 - 2 (months)
        </a>
    </div>
```

I keep getting this error

> Missing required parameters for [Route: vaccine1] [URI: clinic/{farm}]. (View: /Users/macair13/MeatracProject/resources/views/clinic/show.blade.php)

which I do not get why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do is just, pass the object `$farm` and I'll automatically generate an URL to this route so it becomes like that

```
 http://example.com/clinic/{farm}
to
 http://example.com/clinic/1  <!-- if the Id was 1
```

```
<div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="{{ route('vaccine1', $farm->id)}}">
            0 - 2 (months)
        </a>
</div>
```

or like that

```
<div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="{{ route('vaccine1', ['farm' => $farm->id ])">
            0 - 2 (months)
        </a>
</div>
```

More info check out the docs for [URLs For Named Routes](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/urls#urls-for-named-routes)

Comment: In both method when I use it, it returning to the show.blade.php

Comment: because both methods are returning to /clinic/`show.blade.php`  as shown here `return view('clinic.show',compact('farms'));` ,

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to generate a URL for a route that has a required parameter, `'/clinic/{farm}'`. When calling the `route` helper you will need to pass a value for that parameter or have set a default parameter on the UrlGenerator.

`route('vaccine1', ['farm' => ...])`

Answer (score 1):

You forget to add a `farm` parameter when you try to render the `vaccine1` route

You should render it like this

```
<a class="dropdown-item" href="{{ route('vaccine1', ['farm' => $farm->id]) }}">
        0 - 2 (months)
</a>
```